# Is the balancing easier on big cycles after the kid learns to ride pedal less bicycle?

Tags: pedals, children

Is the balancing easier on big cycles after the kid learns to ride pedal less bicycle?

Kid is 2 years 8 months old. Is this a correct age to go for such a cycle?

Comment: I got my daughter one when she was about the same age and it works great!

Comment: It helps to learn balance and steering and gain confidence.  Another trick is to just take the pedals off a regular bike and let them motor for a while.

Comment: The big advantage I found with runner bikes is that they work much better when the ground is uneven. Sidewalks are often banked to allow water to more easily run off them.  Training wheels are terrible in this situation because they restrict the bike from standing upright. They want to stand at the same angle as the sidewalk or bike path.  Using a runner bike or a regular bicycle without training wheels allows the bike to remain upright, making it easier to balance.

Answer (score 2):

If they are steady on their feet and tall enough than a balance bike is fine.
The advantage of a balance bike is it develops balance first as small children don't necessarily have the strength or co-ordination to ride a pedal bike to begin with.

We found the wooden balance bikes to be inherently bigger - so for our child we went with the much smaller dimensions the aluminium balance bikes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the balancing easier on big cycles after the kid learns to ride pedal less bicycle?

The world is full of variation!

Anacdotally, learning on a balance bike (no pedals) first, then transitioning to a pedal bike seems to work very well. This worked well for my mine and the neighbour's kids as we all seemed to transition without any major crashes.  It did take some time to figure out the process of pedalling and braking.

That said, my nephew received his first bike (a pedal bike) at 4, and in two weeks had learnt how to ride it on his own. He was seriously motivated watching all the other kids ride their bike.

> Kid is 2 years 8 months old. Is this a correct age to go for such a cycle?

Assuming you child has hit all the major developmental milestones this seems to be the age many parents try balance bikes. This is of course anecdotal evidence, but the fact I have seen so many different families consistently start at around this age seems to suggest it is a good starting place.

Answer (score 2):

My oldest is now 12 - Balance bikes were not readily available 10 years ago in my country. If I did it over again, I would use a balance bike (or take the pedals off a normal bike).

Balance bikes provide a natural and safe learning progression. Most kids have come off some sort of sit astride plastic toy, a balance bike is really a 'big kids' version of what they are used to. They then naturally progress on it as the build confidence and competence.  Eventually they will be able to everything you do on a normal bike except pedal. The transition to  a real bike with pedals is then another natural progression.

Other options - trainer -teach bad habits that need to be corrected, or straight onto a proper bike wheeler "deep ends" them - they have to learn a lot very quickly, or get hurt... Neither experience makes for a great way to teach someone or for them to learn.

Answer (score 1):

A person is better-trained to understand the mechanics and physics of balance, so for example coasting down a gradual hill on a pedal-bike the first time will be easier for someone who has ridden a stride-bike, but the mechanics of moving the feet in circles while pedaling and balancing will still take some time. The transition from striding to pedaling could still be tricky and require some courage, but it should be easier than of the stride bike was not used.

I can't comment on whether a particular child is ready for a stride bike, but if the kid can operate it, go for it.